# Crossdomain ajax wth jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I want to call AJAX on `subdomain` using jquery `ajax()` method:
I call it from http://domain.com/

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url:'https://sub.domain.com/',
    success: function(response) {
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, calls error function with `resp == {
status:0, readyState: 0, responseText : '', statusText: 'error'
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-domain ajax calls are also cross domain. This is even true if they point to the same place (like example.com and www.example.com). They (usually) point to the same place. We see them as the same thing. But to an Ajax call, it's considered cross domain.

Please do a search on crossdomain ajax and you'll find a lott to go on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CORS for this purpose.

Example code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; 

function CrosDom_ajax(url) {
        if (window.XDomainRequest
        && $.browser.msie
        && $.browser.version < 10) {
        xdr = new XDomainRequest();
        if (xdr) {
            xdr.onload = function () {
               alert(xdr.responseText);

            };
            xdr.open("get", url);
            xdr.send();
        }
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function (response) {


                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
         }
    }
```

Also you need to Write the following code in server side, to allow cross domain access

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```